Custom dotnet counters in Visual Studio
In this pane:

I am running the example application from Microsoft. This defines a counter
static Meter s_meter = new Meter("HatCo.Store");
static Counter<int> s_hatsSold = s_meter.CreateCounter<int>("hatco.store.hats_sold");

and runs a loop incrementing the counter. I expected the counter to appear in the Counters pane. It doesn't?
(I also have attempted to retrofit counters to an existing ASP.NET application, but those don't show up at all, even the System.Runtime ones, even with dotnet-counters. I fear that's going to be harder to diagnose.)
Does anyone know how the counter monitoring actually works and connects to the process? Pipe or socket? Can you view your own counters from within the program?

In the relevant MS document, the recommended way to view custom counters is to use the dotnet-counters tool and custom counters cannot be observed in the Diagnostics Tools panel. To clarify the process, I've captured key moments in the implementation, showcasing how to use dotnet-counters for displaying of these metrics.
1.Create an ASP.NET Web Application project.
2.Tools>Command Line>Developer Powershell.

3.Enter dotnet tool update -g dotnet-counters to install dotnet tool.

4.
Replace the contents of Program.cs with the following code:
using System.Diagnostics.Metrics;
 
class Program
{
   static Meter s_meter = new("HatCo.HatStore", "1.0.0");
   static Counter<int> s_hatsSold = s_meter.CreateCounter<int>("hats-sold");
 
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var rand = Random.Shared;
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
       while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
       {
           //// Simulate hat selling transactions.
          Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(100, 2500));
          s_hatsSold.Add(rand.Next(0, 1000));
       }
   }
}


Run the project.
In powershell comand line ,enter：dotnet-counters monitor -n WebApplication2 HatCo.HatStore

Output picture like this:



That's just a copy of the web page I linked? I suppose "custom counters are not displayed in VS" is useful information even if it's not a useful feature.

GoodDay! Currently, there isn’t any official documentation available on displaying custom counters in the Diagnostic Tools panel. you might consider looking for an extension in the VS extensions marketplace to help you watch your counters in the panel.
